ICMPv6 Checksum Calculation With Extension(s) in the IPv6 header
I'm trying to calculate the ICMPv6 checksum, but I'm getting the wrong checksum when the IPv6 header contains extension(s). I get the correct checksum value when the IPv6 header contains no extensions.
To calculate the ICMPv6 checksum, I first construct The IPv6 pseudo-header in this order:
IPv6 Src Address, IPv6 Dst Address, IPv6 Payload Length as std::uint32_t type (although it is stored as std::uint16_t type), three zeros, and the IPv6 Next Header (I always set it to 0x3a for the ICMPv6 protocol).
For the ICMPv6 header, I take the following in this order, the Type, the Code, and the payload/data.
To calculate the checksum, I prepend the IPv6 pseudo-header to the ICMPv6 header, and calculate the checksum. This implementation produces the correct checksum when the IPv6 header contains no extensions. However, when the IPv6 header contains extensions, for example, the Routing Header for IPv6 extension, it produces the wrong checksum. As you can tell, I do not account for the extensions at all in the checksum calculation.
Any idea what is it that I'm doing wrong?
TIA.

I solved it.
To answer myself. In the presence of the Routing Header extension in the IPv6 header, the IPv6 dst address will be the final address in the list of the extension. Moreover, we subtract the length of any extension headers between the IPv6 header and the next layer, from the Payload length. The IPv6 Next Header is always set to 0x3a for ICMPv6.
